# Conflict during git rebase whereas files don't exist in local branch

Tags: git

I have a branch where only sources are tracked and another branch where some generated files are tracked too.

- In branch "production": there are 2 tracked directories src and build
- In branch "dev" I untracked (and removed) build/

When I rebase "dev" on "production" (usual sync) I get conflicts with messages like (it's in french so I translated) `CONFLICT: build/xxx removed in <commit> and modified in HEAD.`

Is there something wrong in my config ? What is the proper way to solve this ?

Comment: If you want the folder to remain untracked on your dev branch, delete it then add its path before committing, or else it'll be created and become tracked even on this branch. But note that you'll have this conflict again each time something changes in one of these folders, which probably means *each time*.

Comment: You mean: after the rebase, do a `git add <folder>` then `git rebase --continue` ? It is what I am doing but I have to do it manually for every commit

Answer (score 0):

If you want `dev` to permanently not track `build/` then you can add it to `.gitignore`. Otherwise you will get conflicts for all changes in that directory on rebases/merges.

Comment: Good idea except that ythe .gitignore of dev is replaced by the .gitignore of production so build/ is not ignored